# react native: view not shows in android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a header which contain component. This header should have shadow in android and iOS. it's work on iOS but not show anything in android.

```
class Toolbar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.toolBar, this.props.style]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  toolBar: {
    zIndex: 1,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    height: topBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: colors.base,
    elevation: 5,
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 1,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 2,
      width: 0
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html#props), Shadow Props (`shadowColor`, `shadowOffset`, `shadowOpacity` and `shadowRadius`) only work in iOS.

Comment: Yes, they are just for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use zIndex and elevation  in one style, if you do the view not shown. set zIndex to zero for android.

```
zIndex: (Platform.OS == 'ios') ? 1 : 0
```